# Typescript generic class as Angular2 component

Tags: angular, templates, generics, typescript

Is it possible to use Typescript template/generic class as Angular2 component? 
If yes, could you give me/point me to a sample code please?

Elaborating my question futher:
I want to display multiple lists in my application. They are visually/functionally same but basically lists of different types for example, `IFruits`, `IVegetables`, `IGrains`, etc. So, I've been thinking of making a component somewhat like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-list-display',
})
export class MyListDisplayComponent<T> {
  private list: T[];

  // further code to display and perform operations on list... 
}
```

Does it even makes sense?
Is there an alternative to achieving this?
Please enlighten me!

Comment: `generic class as component` is too broad can you be specific.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to indicate that the property `list` is one of a selection of types, there are a few options I know of. You could create an interface like `ListItem` which multiple classes implement. You could also create an `abstract class ListItem` which multiple classes either `extend` / `implement`. For example

```
export abstract class ListItem {
  public name: string;
}

export class Fruit implements ListItem {
  public name: string;
}

export class Vegetable extends ListItem {
}


@Component({
  selector: 'my-list-display',
})
export class MyListDisplayComponent {
  private list: ListItem[];

  // further code to display and perform operations on list... 
}
```

Using an interface would be similar

```
export interface ListItem {
  name: string;
}

export class Fruit implements ListItem {
  public name: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-list-display',
})
export class MyListDisplayComponent {
  private list: ListItem[];

  // further code to display and perform operations on list... 
}
```

If the `Fruit` class is actually `FruitComponent`, usage is the same (i.e. `FruitComponent implements ListItem`)